# vaadin combobox item label and item value

Tags: java, vaadin

I am a new Vaadin user with JSF background.Currently i am trying to implement a simple
combobox using vaadin.What i want to do is,using a List as the itemlist of the combobox,showing Example.description field in the combobox,and when one of the items selected getting the Example object/Example.id as value.(as we do in JSF using itemLabel=example.description,itemValue=example/example.id properties of f:selectItems)

Comment: currently object ids are shown in the combobox like (tw.com.tiri.City@d75415)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this is Ville from the Vaadin team. You can do this in quite many ways but in general you toggle your ComboBox behavior with the *setItemCaptionMode()* method.

However, pretty close to what you are trying to do is accomplished with the following example:

```
public class Example {

    private Integer id;
    private String description;

    public Example(Integer id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}

@Override
public void init() {
    Window mainWindow = new Window("Combobox Application");

    List<Example> examples = new ArrayList<Example>();
    examples.add(new Example(new Integer(1), "First description"));
    examples.add(new Example(new Integer(2), "Second description"));
    examples.add(new Example(new Integer(3), "Third description"));
    BeanItemContainer<Example> objects = new BeanItemContainer(Example.class, examples);

    ComboBox combo = new ComboBox("Example", objects);
    combo.setItemCaptionPropertyId("description");

    mainWindow.addComponent(combo);
    setMainWindow(mainWindow);
}
```

Here the BeanItemContainer wraps your POJOs and uses reflection to access getters.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to vaadin so I can't provide you with a good solution, but you could try and use some wrapper object per entry and override the `toString()` method to print out the city name.

Besides that you could try and use a `BeanContainer<String, City>` as the datasource for that combobox. The string would be the city name/id.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more elegant way for Enum class:

```
 public enum Planet {
    MERCURY,
    VENUS,
    EARTH,
    MARS,
    JUPITER,
    SATURN,
    URANUS,
    NEPTUNE,
    PLUTO;
    public String getCaption(){
        return name();
    }
    public int getId(){
        return ordinal();
    }
}

BeanContainer<Integer, Planet> container =  new BeanContainer<>(Planet.class);
container.setBeanIdProperty("id");
container.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(Planet.class));

ComboBox planet = new ComboBox("Planet", container);
planet.setItemCaptionPropertyId("caption");
```

Autor: 
Andris Lapinsh

https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/280467/280466

Answer (score 0):

With vaadin 8/java 8 you can use:

ComboBox combo = new ComboBox("Example", objects);

combo.setItemCaptionGenerator(example -> example.getDescription());